# How to sort a list of structs based on the lastName variable of the struct

Tags: sorting, go

Before you ask, yes, I must use a list. I can not use a slice or anything else.
So, I have a list full of structures, but the list needs to be sorted based on the lastname variable of the struct. I've tinkered with things but ultimately have nothing to show for it. I'm not asking for an answer, but just some guidance in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So since you *have* to use a golang list, I'd recommend looking into

- [The `list` documentation for Go](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/), especially the functions that move elements
- [Linked lists in Go](http://www.golangprograms.com/golang-program-for-implementation-of-linked-list.html)
- Different ways to sort linked lists, like [merge sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/)

Solutions involving slices likely won't help you since you'll have to do linked list comparisons (and Go's implementation of lists is a little complicated!) Another hint: you'll likely have to do `for loop` iterations, so expect some O(n^2) complexity.

Hope this helps! :)